# ThinkPad X1 Carbon (5th Gen, 2017) BIOS update: Canonical ahead of Lenovo?

Tags: software-center, lenovo, thinkpad, bios

As of yesterday, **Ubuntu Software Center** wants to upgrade the BIOS to version 0.1.**35** while [Lenovo is still only offering version 0.1.**34**](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x1-carbon-type-20hr-20hq/downloads/ds120390).

---

*Compare and contrast*

## Ubuntu Software Center

[image]

*with*

## Lenovo

[image]

---

How could that happen?

---

#### Edit:

## Lenovo (updated; Oct 22 2018)

[image]

It indeed seems to have been the case that Canonical was ahead of Lenovo. But why and how is still a mystery: Since originally posting, Lenovo seems to have caught up with Canonical: both now refer to version 0.1.**35**.

Comment: Could you please mention your version and distro? Also, was Ubuntu pre-installed on your machine? And what is the exact package name for this BIOS update? I'm curious because I have a Dell laptop with Ubuntu 16.04 installed by Dell but I haven't been offered an update to 18.04 or a BIOS update the last time I booted into that OS.

Comment: Thinkpad came with clean slate (nothing pre-installed); Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS. How can I find out the exact package name of the proposed upgrade (without accidentally triggering it)?

Comment: PS: The early BIOS upgrades I did *via* Lenovo, later ones I did (much more simply) with the Ubuntu Software Center. But this is the first time that the version numbers do not match (USC > Lenovo).

Comment: I guess you could try the terminal route and press `n` when you get the `Y/n` prompt.

Comment: Maybe I should boot into Ubuntu 18.04 and see what the Software Center offers. Thanks for bringing this up!

Comment: Similar situation right now: Ubuntu Software Center offers 0.1.34 -> 0.1.36, while Lenovo's website offers 1.37.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be an actual update to install.

I am seeing the same update prompt on Ubuntu 18.04.1, but clicking on `update` only temporarily removes the prompt, before it reappears a few seconds later.

When attempting to update via command line, I see zero updates available with the following:

`sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Apologies if this is more "speculation" and "commentary" rather than an actual "answer". Tried to post this info as a comment, but don't have enough rep points.

Answer (score 0):

## Lenovo (updated; Oct 22 2018)

https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x1-carbon-type-20hr-20hq/downloads/ds120390

[image]

It indeed seems to have been the case that Canonical was ahead of Lenovo. But why and how is still a mystery: Since originally posting, Lenovo seems to have caught up with Canonical: both now refer to version 0.1.**35**.

One logical explanation could be that Canonical is privvy to a faster update release channel (from Lenovo) than the Lenovo website itself. But this is just speculation.